# Is the wolf howl a cosmetic I've equipped?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-hypixel-bedwars

When I get a kill in Bedwars, I hear a wolf howl, which is really cool.
Is this a default sound for kills in Bedwars, or is this a cosmetic I equipped without realizing it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it is a death cry selected by the players i killed, so it wasn't anything i equipped.  bummer.